# How do you activate text2speech on my windows 8 kindle app?

Tags: windows-8, kindle, text-to-speech

Is it possible to activate the text-to-speech setting that is available on the kindle on my windows 8 kindle app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install external screen reader software for this.
Amazon [recommends](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000632481) two programs for this:

> In order to use the text-to-speech feature in Kindle for PC, an
>   external screen reader program must be installed and running on the
>   Windows PC. Tested screen readers include JAWS and NVDA.